# how to place an element outside of bootstrap container width

Tags: html, css

I've been screwing around with a test website. I'm using bootstrap and know you should put everything into a container div, which gives everything inside a padding or margin?

I'm fine with that but wanted to have a carousel that takes up the full width of the viewport instead of having the space around it at the top. How do I do this?

I could just put it outside of the container, but I heard you shouldn't do this, and I need to have a nav bar on top that's inside the container so I think overall that's not a good idea.

What way could I achieve this while following "good practices"?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a div with class `container-fluid` instead of `container`. The container-fluid takes up the whole width of viewport available.

Comment: how do i do it without using container-fluid? i don't want to change the layout of anything else except for the one carousel

Comment: I dont think it changes anything other but gets rid of the margin. Have you tried it??Did it give any weired resultts??

Comment: it does, but of everything else as well. i managed to do what i want with another method though, but thanks for your help!